# QGIS switch of coordinate system?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, xyz

I want to know if it is possible to switch of the coordinate system in QGIS, because I want to use my own values like x,y,z (the results is a 3D-model and the x,y,z axis is represented in cm, so I do not use and do not need GPS coordinates). In the end it is like my own "local coordinate system".

Answer (score 3):

The tool Reproject Layer does this for you. I think you want to reproject your data from a sphere (WGS84) to a flat (projected) system.

I wrote [another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281401/bringing-drone-maps-into-qgis-crs-and-scale-bar/281410#281410) to [Bringing drone maps into QGIS, CRS and scale bar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281401) which was about this subject and might help.